# How to find the owner of a Sharepoint calendar?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, sharepoint-permissions, manager

My organization uses a SharePoint calendar to track leave, we now have a new supervisor, but nobody knows who owns the calendar to have them give the new supervisor permission to edit it.

Is there a way to view who is the owner or a list of people with edit permission?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check the list permissions by using the account of **Site collection administrator**.

**Useful References**:

1. [What Is a SharePoint Site Collection Administrator?](https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/what-is-a-sharepoint-site-collection-administrator)
2. [Customize permissions for a SharePoint list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly check the permission on that list by going to the calendar ribbon>list settings>Permissions for this list.

[image]
[image]